# Getting an error when I try to insert data into the database in VS-2010

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite

```
Try
Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
Dim SQLcommand As SQLiteCommand
SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database\db" & ";"
SQLconnect.Open()     ' VS highlights this line 
SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
SQLcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Status) VALUES ('Enabled')"
SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLcommand.Dispose()
SQLconnect.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox("Error: Operation unsuccessfull")
End Try
```

Getting an error  when I try to insert data in to the databse,

Error: The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception.

How Can I solve this problem ?

**Edit 1:**

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I tried it without using Try Catch Block

```
Dim sqlConnection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
Dim sqlCommand As New SQLiteCommand
sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=db.s3db"  'is it because of the extension of the database ?
sqlConnection.Open()
sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Status) VALUES ('Enabled')"
sqlConnection.Close()
```

Is it because of the database extension ? I used  sqlite Admin to create tables

**Edit 3:**

I just tried it out in VS 2008, it works flawlessly. Why is it not working in VS 2010. Does it something  have to do with app.config file ? or .net framework 4 ?

This is what I added in the app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
<configSections>..................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the error

> The type initializer for
>   'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace'
>   threw an exception

because I added this line to app.config

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Without removing the old entry

```
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

I replaced the old entry with the new entry. Voila the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the connection in the Finally-Statement of your Try/Catch. Otherwise the connection might keep open when an exception occurs.

Another option is to use the [Using-Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) what automatically closes the Connection and disposes objects. For example:

```
Using SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database\db" & ";")
   SQLconnect.Open()
   ' .... '
End Using
```

Comment: I don't think this is because of the try catch because I was getting this  error even when there was no try catch block .

Comment: Also After the error VS highlights this line **SQLconnect.Open()**

Answer (score 0):

Try run the application with Administrator privileges.(If you are using Visual Studio, right click on the Shortcut, Select Run As Administrator. You can also set this in the Properties.)

Seems like similar issue : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98437/sqlconnection-open-fails-because-of-system-transactions-diagnostics-diagnostictrace-for-non-admin-user

Comment: I am working under Windows XP SP3 Pro, I double checked, I do have administrator privileges.